# MiXiM Simulator: Collecting total radio transmitting/idle times?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, inet, mixim

I'm developing a MAC layer protocol and I need to collect physical layer total radio idle and transmitting times.

I've found that the INET framework provides this automatically, but I've been searching for the past 10 days for a similar solution under MiXiM without success.

Is there any method to do this built into Omnet++ or MiXiM? I assume this is a very common metric?

Thanks very much for any pointers.

Best wishes,
Jose Fonseca

Comment: Which physical layer are you using? Which version of MiXiM is this based on?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Decider80211.cc under MiXiM 2.3